# Docker commit not saving files

Tags: docker, guacamole

I'm running a `glyptodon/guacamole` in a docker.

I want to enable the [db auth extension](http://guacamole.incubator.apache.org/doc/gug/jdbc-auth.html) and the process is to move `guacamole-auth-jdbc-mysql-0.9.9.jar` from `GUACAMOLE_HOME/extensions` to `GUACAMOLE_HOME/lib`, and then restart the process.

I am do the following:

```
># docker exec -it some-guacamole bash
># cp /root/.guacamole/extensions/guacamole-auth-jdbc-mysql-0.9.9.jar /root/.guacamole/lib/
># exit
># docker commit <container id> adampski:dbauthv1
># docker stop some-guacamole
># docker rm some-guacamole
># docker run --name some-guacamole --link some-guacd:guacd --link some-mysql:mysql -e MYSQL_DATABASE=guacamole_db -e MYSQL_USER=username -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=password -d -p 8080:8080 adampski:dbauthv1
```

However when I enter the docker with bash and browse to `/root/.guacamole/lib/`, I do not see the file in there.

My understanding is that since I updated the image and ran `docker run` referencing the new image + tag, then it should run a new container with the changes - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a workaround to my problem by pulling the repository, editing `start.sh` to add `guacamole-auth-jdbc-mysql-0.9.9.jar` to `$GUACAMOLE_LIB`. The Dockerfile calls this script when creating the image.